# Search and replace all next word

Tags: search

If I had something like a list of `#define`s in a c file, say

```
#define a
#define cd
#define blah
```

and I wanted to replace all the `#define`s to capitalized characters, can I do this in a single substitution command? Maybe with regex?

I'm thinking something along the lines of `:%s/a/A`, but more of a general command so that I can apply it just once and it gets used on all of the `#define`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `\U` flag in substitutions to substitute the uppercase version. This will work for the first word on every line:

```
:%s/\(\w\+\)/\U\1/
```

This uses memory parentheses `\( \)` to capture the first word and then `\1` in the substitution to "remember" what we've captured.

If you want to get words that aren't at the beginning you might just have to use the word itself:

```
:%s/\(define\)/\U\1/
```

See [`:help s/\U`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#s%2F%5CU) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very close to this one: [How to execute command on every matching pattern, not just lines?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/13464/626)

The difference is that you don't want to remove the next word, but to change it to uppercase.

Mixed with @Tumbler41's solution that changes `define` into `DEFINE`, it becomes:

```
:%s/pattern\zs\s\+\S\+/\U&/g
```

This time `define foo` becomes `define FOO`

Note that thanks to `\zs` we don't need a capture group here. We can use `&` which is similar to `\0`: it contains the complete text matched -- except the context that is matched with a zero-width (`\zs`)

Of course all other solutions will work: you can use `gUw` instead of `dw`, but I'm a `:%s` guy, hence my answer :)